# How to modify JFrame using JRootPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, titlebar, custom-titlebar

I want to remove title bar from `JFrame` and then using `JRootPane` I want to create custom title bar component in Synth L&F. I have searched and found that I can customize frame's look by using the root pane.

How to modify `JFrame` using `JRootPane`?

Comment: Well, this may not be the best thing you can do, but you can make your `JFrame` undecorated (`JFrame#setUndecorated(true)`) and then create your own title bar that way.

Comment: But i want JMenuBar in my application and i don't know how to place at bottom of the custom title bar.

Comment: I want to make the same hierarchy that TitleBar->MenuBar-> then other components